# Go Fyne project can't cross compile from Linux to Windows

Tags: go, cross-compiling, cgo, fyne

I made a Go fyne project, which works fine with `go run .`, and builds to Linux as expected with `go build .`.

However, when I try cross-compiling to windows using `env GOOS=windows GOARCH=arm64 go build .` it prints this error:

```
go: downloading github.com/tevino/abool v1.2.0
package playground.com/colors
    imports fyne.io/fyne/v2/app
    imports fyne.io/fyne/v2/internal/driver/glfw
    imports fyne.io/fyne/v2/internal/driver/common
    imports fyne.io/fyne/v2/internal/painter/gl
    imports github.com/go-gl/gl/v3.1/gles2: build constraints exclude all Go files in /home/mohamed/code/go/pkg/mod/github.com/go-gl/gl@v0.0.0-20211210172815-726fda9656d6/v3.1/gles2
```

I tried a clean install of Go, tried using `go clean -modcache`, tried creating a separate new module.

The code for error replication:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "image/color"

    "fyne.io/fyne/v2"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/app"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/canvas"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/container"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/widget"
)

func main() {
    app := app.NewWithID("Color Mixer")
    window := app.NewWindow("Color")

    red := widget.NewSlider(0, 255)
    green := widget.NewSlider(0, 255)
    blue := widget.NewSlider(0, 255)

    red_value := widget.NewLabel("0")
    green_value := widget.NewLabel("0")
    blue_value := widget.NewLabel("0")

    red_label := widget.NewLabel("Red")
    green_label := widget.NewLabel("Green")
    blue_label := widget.NewLabel("Blue")

    colorx := color.NRGBA{R: 0, G: 0, B: 0, A: 255}
    rect := canvas.NewRectangle(colorx)
    rect.SetMinSize(fyne.NewSize(300, 300))

    red.OnChanged =
        func(f float64) {
        _, g, b, a := rect.FillColor.RGBA()
        rect.FillColor = color.NRGBA{R: uint8(f),
            G: uint8(g),
            B: uint8(b),
            A: uint8(a)}
        rect.Refresh()
        red_value.SetText(fmt.Sprintf("%.0f", f))
        }

    green.OnChanged =
        func(f float64) {
        r, _, b, a := rect.FillColor.RGBA()
        rect.FillColor = color.NRGBA{R: uint8(r),
            G: uint8(f),
            B: uint8(b),
            A: uint8(a)}
        rect.Refresh()
        green_value.SetText(fmt.Sprintf("%.0f", f))
        }

    blue.OnChanged =
        func(f float64) {
        r, g, _, a := rect.FillColor.RGBA()
        rect.FillColor = color.NRGBA{R: uint8(r),
            G: uint8(g),
            B: uint8(f),
            A: uint8(a)}
        rect.Refresh()
        blue_value.SetText(fmt.Sprintf("%.0f", f))
        }

    box := container.NewGridWithRows(
        2,
        container.NewGridWithRows(3, red_label, green_label, blue_label, red, green, blue, red_value, green_value, blue_value),
        rect)

    window.SetContent(box)
    window.ShowAndRun()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC, cross-compilation by default disables `cgo`, and since all the files in that `github.com/go-gl/gl/v3.1/gles2` package make use of it, the building process naturally excludes them all, and produces the error you're seeing.

Hence try building while having `CGO_ENABLED=1` in your environment.
A simple

```
CGO_ENABLED=1 GOOS=windows go build
```

should do the trick.

Note that in order for the build process to actually produce the expected outcome you need to have the C cross-compiler for your target `GOOS`/`GOARCH` combo installed, and probably communicated to the `go` tool via setting the `CC` environment variable—see [the docs](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/cgo).

For instance, on Debian and its derivatives you will probably need to have the following packages installed:

- `gcc-mingw-w64-x86-64-win32` — for building for `windows/amd64`.
- `gcc-mingw-w64-i686-win32` — for building for `windows/386`.

The values to set the `CC` variable will be `/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-gcc` and `/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc`, correspondingly.

I have no idea whether there's a MinGW cross-compiler package to target `windows/arm64` which you seem to require, though, as I have zero experience with Windows on ARM devices.

Also note that in order to produce a sensible Windows executable image file while cross-compiling you will probably want to also have `CGO_LDFLAGS=-static-libgcc` in your environment as well—this will produce a binary not dependent on `libgcc.dll`, and maybe you will even want to have `CGO_LDFLAGS=-static-libgcc -static` to have a fully-static build.

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate answer.
For anyone looking for the final command `env CGO_ENABLED=1 GOOS=windows GOARCH=amd64 CC=/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc go build .`

Comment: There are also some Fyne specific hints in our documentation https://developer.fyne.io/started/cross-compiling

Answer (score 1):

The previous answer is correct. However you may like to use the “fyne package” command or fyne-cross - these tools aim to avoid all the manual setup.

Comment: I didn't realize that these existed. I tried installing them using `go install`, but I can't seem to get my terminal to recognize them as commands.

Comment: Maybe your Go install did not add $GOPATH/bin to your $PATH?

Comment: For some reason Go installed them in `~/code/go/bin` instead of `/usr/local/go/bin`. However, fyne-cross is downloading a big docker image and my internet is not stable enough to do so at the moment. I appreciate your suggestion and will use fyne-cross when I am able to.

Comment: Yes, that is the location that “go instal” uses - which is why the go installer should have added it to your PATH env